# Vue 3 and Storybook - migrating from 6.3.3 to 6.3.4 breaks Storybook

Tags: vuejs3, storybook

I recently upgraded my Vue 3 Storybook project from 6.3.3 to 6.3.4 using `npx sb upgrade`. Now I get the following error when running Storybook:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
at exports.provide ({my-folder-path}node_modules\webpack\lib\util\MapHelpers.js:17:20)
at {my-folder-path}node_modules\webpack\lib\DefinePlugin.js:290:6
at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create ({my-folder-path}node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook ({my-folder-path}node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
at Compiler.newCompilation ({my-folder-path}node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:631:26)
at {my-folder-path}node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:667:29
at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create ({my-folder-path}node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook ({my-folder-path}node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
at Compiler.compile ({my-folder-path}node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:662:28)
at {my-folder-path}node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:77:18
at _next0 (eval at create ({my-folder-path}node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
at eval (eval at create ({my-folder-path}node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:34:1)
at watchRunHook ({my-folder-path}node_modules\webpack-virtual-modules\index.js:173:5)
at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create ({my-folder-path}node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:30:1)
at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook ({my-folder-path}node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
at Watching._go ({my-folder-path}node_modules\@storybook\builder-webpack4\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:41:32)
```

I'm kind of a webpack nube so I'm at a bit of a loss here.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my issue was not related to the storybook upgrade but was because of my version of npm was not loading conflicting packages anymore (I updated to 7.19.0 recently). I now have to run `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` to get things going.